# Trouble rendering images in markdown with gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-remark-image

I'm using the following GatsbyJS starter: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/jannikbuschke/gatsby-antd-docs/

I'm trying to render an image in a markdown file like so:
`![US Energy Infrastructure Visualization](/src/images/us-viz.png)`

The markdown file is located at `contents/docs/templates/use-cases/us-energy-infrastructure.md`

The image is located at `src/images/us-viz.png`

The result is as follows:
[image]

The console and network tabs show a 404 error for the requested image file:
[image]

[image]

This is the contents of my `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Energy Infrastructure API Documentation',
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-typescript`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-json`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `menuItems`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/menuItems`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `sidebar`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/sidebar`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `contents`,
        path: `${__dirname}/contents`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: 'gatsby-starter-markdown',
        short_name: 'starter',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/gatsby-icon.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [`gatsby-remark-images`],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        defaultLayouts: {
          default: require.resolve('./src/Layout.tsx'),
        },
        extensions: ['.mdx', '.md'],
        // workaround: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/16422#issuecomment-518985316
        plugins: [`gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          `gatsby-remark-katex`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1035,
            },
          },
          `gatsby-remark-autolink-headers`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {
              classPrefix: 'language-',
              inlineCodeMarker: null,
              showLineNumbers: true,
              noInlineHighlight: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.app/offline
    // 'gatsby-plugin-offline',
  ],
  /// this must match the path your webpage is displayed from (the second part of the ternary will be the path prefix for production)
  pathPrefix: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '' : '',
}
```

It appears to meet the necessary requirements for using the Transformer Remark plugin as specified in the [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/)

As far as I can tell the method I'm using for inserting the image into my markdown file should work, I'm not sure what's going on here. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gatsby-remark-images plugin documentation:

> You can reference an image in markdown using the relative path, where that path is relative to the location of the Markdown file you’re typing in.

[gatsby-remark-images documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-images/?=gatsby-remark-i#usage-in-markdown)

So if your markdown path is:

```
contents/docs/template/use-cases/us-energy-infrastructure.md
```

And your image location is:

```
src/images/us-viz.png
```

You should reference your image file from markdown like so:

```
![Alt text here](../../../../src/images/us-viz.png)
```

Comment: This works in development when run locally but breaks when deployed with surge.sh

Comment: Why you don't try running your production app locally: npm run build, then npm run serve, and check if it's working. If it's working, and it is because I have checked it, then it looks like the problem lies with your hosting provider. I would suggest trying another one, like Netlify

Comment: interestingly enough the image is working when I build and run `gatsby develop` but not when I run `npm run serve`.